# Need to understand how tracking codes may be working in web content

Tags: javascript, html, analytics

I was recently approached by a web partner and they asked me to add their '*tracking code*' to my site as shown below. The data and address would be different, but the structure is the same as below. Currently they load our site in an IFrame and what I can't understand is...

How could the **script** portion provide any value to them? Can a parent page read JavaScript state of something in a hosted IFrame? Google uses a similar pattern but they set the **src** which has Script that is executed when the page loads and could read the state.

Can anyone explain how this might be working or is this just useless page spam?

```
<img src="https://www.APartnerCompany.foo/thing.img?arg=value" />

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[ 
var Foo = {}; 
Foo.Tracking = {}; 
Foo.Tracking.Sale = {}; 
Foo.Tracking.Sale.amount = '100.00'; 
//]]> 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An inline script can also read values from the page it is contained in. To post them back to their own server, they seem to use the src attribute of that affiliate image. However, the pieces you provided are harmless (the code does nothing than constructing an object) and requests only a non-executable from `https://www.APartnerCompany.foo/thing.img?arg=value` (beeing logged at theirs).

Answer (score 1):

When the request for that src is being sent the server is just logging the variables that are accompanied with it, the JS code is just updating the arguments with relevant data.

Answer (score 0):

All it does is send information to a server through a GET request which it is logged. It can be as simple as reading the Apache logs for hits or it can be a cgi that processes the data. That is basically how all those ad/logging services work.